# trying to split the functions into .c and .h files but got compile error

Tags: c, compilation, header-files

i made a tic tac toe game and tried to split that functions into .c and .h files.

but i got compile error and cannot run.

tried to figure out what the problems are but still trapped.

i don't really know if this error occurred from the wrong .c .h code or wrong gcc compile.

this is a game.c code which has main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ready.h"
#include "game.h"

int play_tictactoe(int board_sz, int computer_enabled );

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    int board_sz = 3;
    int computer_enabled;
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Parse command line arguments using getopt()
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:i")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 's':
            board_sz = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'i':
            computer_enabled = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    play_tictactoe(board_sz, computer_enabled);

    return 0;
}

int play_tictactoe(int board_sz, int computer_enabled ){
    char **Board = create_board(board_sz);
    char winner = '\0';
    char row;
    char col;
    char turn = 'X';

    // standard game loop
    while (!winner && !is_draw(Board, board_sz))
    {
        print_board(Board, board_sz);

        if (turn == 'X' || !computer_enabled)
        {
            printf("computer 'O' Moves are 'enabled'\n");
            printf("-Player's %c turn (qq to quit)\n\n", turn);
// suggestion
            do
            {
                row = rand() % board_sz + 'a'; //
                col = rand() % board_sz + '0';
            } while (Board[row - 'a'][col - '1'] != ' ');
            printf("*---> suggestion:\t(%c %c)\n\n", row, col);


            printf("(X) Enter Move (row column) ---------------------------> ");
            fflush(stdout);
            scanf(" %c %c", &row, &col);

            // quit when enter qq.
            if (row == 'q' && col == 'q'){
              exit(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("computer 'O' Moves are 'enabled'\n");
            printf("*Player's O turn (qq to quit)\n\n\n");
            // Randomly pick a move
            do
            {
                row = rand() % board_sz + 'a'; //
                col = rand() % board_sz + '0';
            } while (Board[row - 'a'][col - '1'] != ' ');

            printf("(O) computer Picks (%c %c) (hit a key to continue)    ----> ", row, col);
        }

        // Make move if square is free
        int rowind = row - 'a';
        int colind = col - '0';
        if (rowind >= board_sz || colind >= board_sz)
        {
            printf("Invalid move\n");
        }
        else if (Board[rowind][colind] == ' ')
        {
            char enter;
            enter = getchar();
            printf("Move is %c %c (%d, %d)\n", row, col, rowind, colind);
            Board[rowind][colind] = turn;
            if (turn == 'X')
            {
                turn = 'O';
            }
            else
            {
                turn = 'X';
            }
            winner = winning_move(Board, board_sz, rowind, colind);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Square is occupied; try again.\n");
        }
    }

    // Game over - print Board & declare finish
    print_board(Board, board_sz);
    if (winner == 'X' || winner == 'O')
        {
        printf("Congratulations %c!\n", winner);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("Game ends in a draw.\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is ready.c code which has gathering functions.

```
#include "ready.h"
#include "game.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <time.h> // srand
#include <unistd.h> // optarg

// Creates nxn tic tac toe Board
char **create_board(int board_sz)
{

    char **Board = (char **)malloc(board_sz * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < board_sz; i++)
    {
        Board[i] = (char *)malloc(board_sz * sizeof(char));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < board_sz; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < board_sz; j++)
        {
            Board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return Board;
}

// Prints the Board
void print_board(char **Board, int board_sz)
{
    printf(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < board_sz; i++)
    {
        printf("|%d", i); // column
    }
    printf("|\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < board_sz; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", 'a' + i); // row
        for (int j = 0; j < board_sz; j++)
        {
            printf("|%c", Board[i][j]); // index for each square
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
}

// Returns true if the game is a draw
int is_draw(char **Board, int board_sz)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board_sz; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < board_sz; j++)
        {
            if (Board[i][j] == ' ')
            {
                // empty square, so game ain't over yet
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // no empty squares, so it's a draw
return 1;
}

// Returns 'X' if (i,j) was a winning move for X
// Returns 'O' if (i,j) was a winning move for O
// Returns ASCII value 0 otherwise
char winning_move(char **Board, int board_sz, int row_index, int col_index)
{
    int win = 1;

    // check row
    for (int k = 0; k < board_sz; k++)
    {
        if (Board[row_index][k] != Board[row_index][col_index])
        {
            win = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (win) // means Board[i][k] == Board[i][j]
    {
        return Board[row_index][col_index];
    }

    // check column
    win = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < board_sz; k++)
    {
        if (Board[k][col_index] != Board[row_index][col_index])
        {
            win = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (win)
    {
        return Board[row_index][col_index];
    }

    // check forward diagonal
    win = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < board_sz; k++)
    {

        if (Board[k][k] != Board[row_index][col_index])
        {
            win = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (win)
    {
        return Board[row_index][col_index];
    }
// check reverse diagonal
    win = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < board_sz; k++)
    {
        if (Board[k][board_sz - k - 1] != Board[row_index][col_index])
        {
            win = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (win)
    {
        return Board[row_index][col_index];
    }

    // got nothing
    return 0;
}
```

this is game.h file

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "ready.h"

int play_tictactoe(int board_sz, int computer_enabled );

#endif
```

this is ready.h

```
#ifndef READY_H
#define READY_H

char **create_board(int board_sz);
void print_board(char **Board, int board_sz);
int is_draw(char **Board, int board_sz);
char winning_move(char **Board, int board_sz, int row_index, int col_index);

#endif
```

i'm actually not sure how to compile correctly,
so i did

'gcc -c game.c -o game'

'gcc -c ready.c -o ready'

those are compiled without error but the Executable or recognized data file not created.
so i did

'gcc game.c create_board.c print_board.c winning_move.c is_draw.c -o game'

'gcc ready.c create_board.c print_board.c winning_move.c is_draw.c -o ready'

and when i compile it like those i got same error on both which are

cc1: fatal error: create_board.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

cc1: fatal error: print_board.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

cc1: fatal error: winning_move.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

cc1: fatal error: is_draw.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a minor warning, your code builds just fine.  Here are two different approaches, the first without `make`, the second with:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c game.c
game.c: In function ‘play_tictactoe’:
game.c:96:18: warning: variable ‘enter’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   96 |             char enter;
      |                  ^~~~~
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c ready.c
$ gcc game.o ready.o -o tic-tac-toe
```

And here using `make` (with no makefile):

```
$ rm *.o tic-tac-toe 
$ rm -f Makefile makefile GNUMakefile *akefile
$ make game.o ready.o
cc    -c -o game.o game.c
cc    -c -o ready.o ready.c
$ gcc game.o ready.o -o tic-tac-toe
```

Note that the `makefile` is not necessary, but if you want it you can also do:

```
$ rm -f *.o tic-tac-toe 
$ printf 'tic-tac-toe: game.o ready.o\n\t$(CC) -o $@ $^\n' > makefile
$ make
cc    -c -o game.o game.c
cc    -c -o ready.o ready.c
cc -o tic-tac-toe game.o ready.o
```

Comment: could you give a little help to make Makefile? 
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -pedantic 
CC = GCC /
all : ready game /

game.o: game.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c game.c /

ready.o: ready.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ready.c /

clean:
        rm -f ready
        rm -f game
        rm -f *.o tic-tac-toe 
        rm -rf *.dSYM 
i wrote like this and got error, not compile successfully. where should i fix it? kinda confused.

Comment: @mjKim You should not have a `ready` or a `game` target, since you are not trying to create files named `ready` or `game`.  You create `ready.o` from `ready.c` and `game.o` from `game.c`, but you never create anything named `ready` or `game` (unless your final exectuable is to be named `game`).  Start by creating the makefile as I did above; it can be just two lines.

Comment: In short, the line `all: ready game` in your makefile doesn't make much sense, as `make` does not know how to make `ready` or `game`.  The recipe should look more like `all: tic-tac-toe` and then another recipe like `tic-tac-toe: ready.o game.o\  $(CC) -o tic-tac-toe ready.o game.o` (the final executable till be named `tic-tac-toe`)

Answer (score 1):

The `-c` option is to create *object files*. These should really be named with an `.o` suffix, like `game.o`. This will be the default if you don't provide the `-o` option.

Then you *link* the object files to create the executable program.

So the commands should be something like:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror game.c -c
$ gcc -Wall -Werror ready.c -c
$ gcc game.o ready.o -o game
```

I only build and use the files actually in your project, not listing any other non-existing files.

Note that I added the `-Wall` and `-Werror` flags, to make sure you get more warnings and that they are treated as errors. This is a good habit.